# Play framework 2 form fields have hasError but how to check a field is valid

Tags: forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.0

I want to use Bootstrap 3 validation states like

```
<div class="form-group has-success">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Input with success</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess1">
</div>
<div class="form-group has-error">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputError1">Input with error</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError1">
</div>
```

how to check the status `success`? Before first submiting the form field has no error, but this does not mean that the field is correct.

Answer (score 1):

looking a little deeper `views.html.helper.FieldElements` and `play.api.data.Field`, i found solution (using this in helper handler)

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

@state = {
    @if(elements.hasErrors) {
        has-error
    } else {
        @if(elements.field.value.isDefined) {
            has-success
        }
    }
}
```

`field.value` is None if `play.api.data.Form` is empty (without filling or binding).

```
val registerForm = Form(
    tuple(
      "firstName" -> nonEmptyText,
      "lastName" -> nonEmptyText        
    )
  )

Ok(views.html.register(registerForm))
```